# How to run a .awk file?

Tags: awk

I am converting a [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file into a table format, and I wrote an AWK script and saved it as my.awk. Here is the my script:

```
#AWK for test
awk -F , '
    BEGIN {
        aa = 0;
    }
    {
        hdng = "fname,lname,salary,city";
        l1 = length($1);
        l13 = length($13);
        if ((l1 > 2) &&  (l13 == 0)) {
            fname = substr($1, 2, 1);
            l1 = length($3) - 4;
            lname = substr($3, l1, 4);
            processor = substr($1, 2);
            #printf("%s,%s,%s,%s\n", fname, lname, salary, $0);
        }

        if ($0 ~ ",,,,")
            aa++
        else if ($0 ~ ",fname")
            printf("%s\n", hdng);
        else if ((l1 > 2) && (l13 == 0)) {
            a++;
        }
        else {
            perf = $11;
            if (perf ~/^[0-9\.\" ]+$/)
                type = "num"
            else
                type = "char";
            if (type == "num")
                printf("Mr%s,%s,%s,%s,,N,N,,\n", $0,fname,lname, city);
        }
    }
    END {
    } ' < life.csv > life_out.csv*
```

How can I run this script on a Unix server? I tried to run this my.awk file by using this command:

```
awk -f my.awk life.csv
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The file you give is a *shell script*, not an awk program. So, try `sh my.awk`.

If you want to use `awk -f my.awk life.csv  > life_out.cs`, then remove `awk -F , '` and the last line from the file and add `FS=","` in `BEGIN`.

Comment: can you pipe output from something like `tail -f` into an `awk` shell script? So I could tail a log file then do some processing with awk then output  it to the screen?

Comment: Actually it looks like stoggy answer below is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 35):

If you put `#!/bin/awk -f` on the first line of your AWK script it is easier. Plus editors like [Vim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29) and ... will recognize the file as an AWK script and you can colorize.  :)

```
#!/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {}  # Begin section
{}        # Loop section
END{}     # End section
```

Change the file to be executable by running:

```
chmod ugo+x ./awk-script
```

and you can then call your AWK script like this:

```
`$ echo "something" | ./awk-script`
```

Comment: You can simply say `chmod +x ...` instead of `chmod ugo+x ...`

Comment: @Calaf: Your edit would be clearer if you placed the `chmod` instruction **before** the `echo "something" | ./awk-script` command.

Comment: @Seamus Good point. Done. (I resisted the temptation to yield to my indignation at Emacs being referred to with "dots" by adding specific instructions that make Emacs's superiority plenty evident.)

Answer (score 19):

Put the part from `BEGIN....END{}` inside a file and name it like my.awk.

And then execute it like below:

```
awk -f my.awk life.csv >output.txt
```

Also I see a field separator as `,`. You can add that in the begin block of the **.awk** file as `FS=","`