# why awk print file content while there is no print command

Tags: awk

i have an awk file, which i read each words from a file into an array, there is no print command in it, but after i run it, the whole content of the file is printed,

```
 #!/bin/awk -f
{
for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
 used[$i]=1
}
```

after i run this awk file like this

```
 awk 1.awk 2
```

the whole content of file 2 is printed on the screen, i am confused,
i tried this directly from command line, there is nothing printed out, so i think there is something wrong with the file or the way to run this file,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the `-f` option: `awk -f 1.awk 2`

What you provided is, instead of the **contents** of "1.awk" as the awk commands, you're providing the **literal string** `1.awk` as the awk command.

You can essentially done this: `awk '"1.awk"' 2`

And since that is a "true" value, the default action is to print each record of the data contained in file "2".

Comment: i add option -f in the file after #!/usr/bin, some articles from online said it will work, now seems it doesn't

Comment: @tonyibm This may help if you want to use that shebang line. https://stackoverflow.com/a/20526774/9217314